# How to show multipul pdf's in django view

Tags: python, django, http-headers, django-views

Is it possible to show multiple PDF files in the Django view, rather than just one?

My current view shows just one

```js
class PdfView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        for pdf in pdfs:
            with open('/path/to/pdf/file/' + pdf.title + '.pdf', 'r') as pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + pdf.title + '.pdf'
                return response
```

I'd like to open as many pdf's as needed, but keep running into 
HTTP ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

edit: here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 217, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 328, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket
```

Comment: @MEE sorry about that. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple temple view and html iframe for that i think.